# Using and input string to find a tuple in a text file

Tags: python-3.x, optimization

This is my code so far. I have tried to get an input from the user to search for a tuple of 3 parts in my source code. But I can not figure out how to allow the user to find the code through input and give them the tuple. If the the name variable is changed to 'Fred' it is found with ease but the code needs for the users input. All help is much appreciated.

```
def details():
   countries = []
    file = open('file.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
    file.readline()
    for line in file:
        parts = line.strip().split(',')
        country = Country(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2])
        countries.append(country)
    file.close()
    with open('file.txt', encoding='utf=8') as countries:
        for country in countries:
            name=str(input('enter:'))
            if str(name) in country:
                print(country)
```

Comment: Where is the tuple? If there isn't one and you're actually searching for the country **object** - we'll need to look at it's implementation.

Comment: Sorry I am a student, and I thought that the Country(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]), was to make it a tuple. The txt is situated as part_0,part_1,part_2 and I was trying to get and input from user that find part_0 and return the row. I guess I have been doind it worng. The furthest I got was if I make the if str(name) in country: to if "fred" in country: I get the row but I need the input to find row.

Comment: Add the class code. This is very partial

Comment: I had figured out how to get it working. But it kind of came with rewriting the whole function though.